# Does Android WebView keep page in RAM only?

Tags: android, caching, webview

I need to know whether WebView keeps a downloaded page only in RAM or does it cache somewhere on a storage so it doesn't necessary load a previous page if it's not needed (like not refreshing). I need to know for security reasons, a client wants to prevent that when a device is lost, the founder won't able to see the last visited pages from the storage. Thank you.

Comment: I think it cache some file on data/data/your.package.name/cache and some store at ram too

Comment: Thnx for your comment. The thing is, the WebView will be only used for reading some information, so it would be on for pages with plain text and some images. No javascript, no flash, no cookies or something. These pages are accessed through a secured tunnel to our own webserver. But on the client side there shouldn't be any traces left of the visited pages.